# Initializing generic slice with size inside a struct

Tags: go, generics, stack, abstract-data-type

I'm trying to build a LIFO stack. I've created a `Stack[T any]` interface and a `dynamicStack[T any]` struct. dynamicStack has a data `[]T` field and an index `int` field. When a `dynamicStack` is created, I want data to be initialized empty, of fixed size 1 and type `T`. Statement comes up: "cannot use [0]T{} (value of type [0]T) as []T value in assignment" when I try to do so.

```
type Stack[T any] interface {
    IsEmpty() bool
    SeeTop() T
    AddToStack(T)
    Unstack() T
}
```

```
type dynamicStack[T any] struct {
    data    []T
    index int
}
```

```
func CreateDynamicStack[T any]() Stack[T] {
    s := new(dynamicStack[T])
    s.data = [0]T{} // Problem
    s.index = 0
    return s
}
```

I've tried using const instead of "0", different sizes and even initializing the array as non-empty but nothing works.

I'm not trying to use `append()` method and I need a fixed size array as my plan is to resize the array whenever it's full or whenever it's half empty.

Any ideas?

Comment: try `d.data=make([]T,1)`. You are trying to create an array, not a slice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`s.data` is a slice, you should initialize it as a slice :

```
s.data = make([]T, 0)
```

Actually, go handles a nil slice pretty much like an empty slice, so you don't even need to initialize `s.data` in your structure. See the example below for an illustration.

---

In go, there is a difference between a [slice type](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Slice_types) `[]T` and an [array type](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Array_types) `[n]T`.

For a detailed explanation of how slices and arrays behave, see this article by Andrew Gerrand:
[Go Slices: usage and internals](https://go.dev/blog/slices-intro)

---

```
// example of slice usage:
func testSlice() {
    var s []int

    fmt.Println("length:", len(s))
    for i, x := range s {
        fmt.Println("iterating:", i, x) // never executed, the slice is empty
    }

    newSlice := append(s, 1)  // a slice allocation happens here
    fmt.Println("result of append(s,1):", newSlice)

    emptySlice := make([]int, 0)

    // the only visible different thing is comparing to nil:
    if s == nil {
        fmt.Println("s is nil")
    }
    if emptySlice == nil {
        fmt.Println("emptySlice is nil") // not printed
    }

    // if you stick to checking the *length* of your slice, you will
    // have a consistent behavior:
    if len(s) == 0 {
        fmt.Println("s is empty")
    }
    if len(emptySlice) == 0 {
        fmt.Println("emptySlice is empty")
    }
}
```

playground: https://go.dev/play/p/kB1g2Iq-n6u